# How can I display my grid in this starter calculator app I am making?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm a begginer in swift. I am starting off my journey with a simple calculator app, but cannot find a way to represent my numbers grid.

I've tried some solutions but just ended up with some errors. I excpected things would go smooth, and for some of these solutions to work. The solutions were just somethings from googling and looking around on youtube.

Comment: Read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show a minimal reproducible code, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your specific usecase or desired layout, but try using `LazyVGrid` or `LazyHGrid` to start. It arranges its children in a grid format that you can customize.

Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvgrid

I also find this article helpful:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-position-views-in-a-grid-using-lazyvgrid-and-lazyhgrid

Comment: I appreicate it! Thank you!